# Why does this assignment statement work in the .NET Framework but not in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

This is a connection string for a database:

```
 private string _connString => $"Data Source={Server.MapPath(@"~\Data")}\\PhoneNumbers.sqlite";
```

My friend used this line in a .NET Framework program and it worked. We both have tried variations of this in .NET Core, but this line is an error. It doesn't have a helpful error code. I think Visual Studio 2017 thinks it's a invalid statement.

Why is this an error?

Comment: **What does the error say**? What kind of error?

Comment: Is the class `Server` in scope in each variation?  ("Scope" isn't exactly the word I'm looking for here, but I'm drawing a blank.  Is it available due to the appropriate `using` statement or whatever?)

Comment: That's the problem. It doesn't give me any useful code. If I paste that line, red lines occur before and after this statement. VS asks me if I want to convert that statement into a method.

Comment: Do you understand what that line of code does ? I find it particulary strange that you use the field naming convention for a property, for instance, although that is not the reason of the error. :)

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong with a string interpolation.

`Server.MapPath` is not available in .NET Core. This class (and a method) is [IIS specific](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx).

The whole point of ASP .NET Core is to make a framework server agnostic, hence there were several new abstractions introduced.

You need to use [`IHostingEnvironment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment) to resolve the path.

[Blog post with an example](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/302/server-mappath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: I get more errors when I try to add 

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

to my program. AspNetCore does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.

Comment: Most probably you need a http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/ NuGet package

Answer (score -1):

String interpolation is a C# 6.0 feature, so **in theory** it should work so long as you have VS2015+. Core 1.0 shipped with C# 6.0. However there may be some differences between the two frameworks that prevent the feature from working in Core. You could just rewrite the line so that the code is backwards compatible.

```
private string _connString = String.Format("Data Source={0}\\PhoneNumbers.sqlite", Server.MapPath(@"~\Data"));
```